# Synchronous call using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I would like to make a synchronous call to server using angular. Something similar to below jquery functionality.

```
var response = $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: "data",
            async: false,
        }).responseText;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have any functions included which are synchronous. You'll have to write something custom with XHR or you'll have to just use a promise. Any reason why you can't use a promise? Angular does have a service called `$q` which can help you with promises. The default `$http` service returns a promise.

Comment: Can you please share some links how to use $q or share some code. I tried some but i couldn't able to do that.